# Deplying Django to Heroku - DisallowedHost Error despite Heroku URL in DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, heroku, config, settings

I've been at this for hours and need help. Initially I thought it was because I had mistakenly done something small that caused it, so I deleted the app, and created everything - virtual env, heroku app, django projects/apps - fresh.

I get the same error.

I made a cookiecutter django app and deployed it to heroku. Everything goes smoothly until it's time to actually use the site.

When I run heroku open, I get the DisallowedHosts error:

**DisallowedHost at /**

**Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'MY-NEW-APP.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'MY-NEW-APP.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.**

heroku config shows that DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=MY-NEW-APP.herokuapp.com. I don't overwrite it in my settings file.

I have import django_heroku and django_heroku.settings(locals()) in my settings file.

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is correctly set to that file.

What's more, I get a warning about DEBUG=True, when DEBUG=False in my settings file and in the heroku environment.

What am I missing? Are hyphens a bad thing? Should I be using herokuapp.com instead of the full URL?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question. I just had to:

```
heroku config:set DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=.MY-NEW-APP.COM,MY-NEW-APP.herokuapp.com,.herokuapp.com
```